# macro loop to copy paste hangs

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me with this loop macro?
I want the loop to copy `Range("S16:Y16").Select`
Move down three rows and paste it, then move down three rows and repeat until it reaches 20.

Error is that it goes down three rows then hangs. Any help would be appreciated

Example code

```
Sub pop1()
    '  Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+f
    '
    Range("S16:Y16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("S19").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("s19:Y19").Select

    For i = 1 To 20
        Selection.Copy
        Range("s19").Offset(3, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: First Things First http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179

Comment: Secondly. If you paste in row 19 and move down 3 places, you have already crossed row 20 or is it that you want to paste 20 times?

Comment: Has any of the answers answered your question? If so please help other users by marking it as the answer, see [about].

Answer (score 2):

If you want to paste 20 times **after** row 19 then try this

```
Sub pop1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        r = 19

        For i = 1 To 21
            .Range("S16:Y16").Copy .Range("S" & r)
            r = r + 3
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

The above will paste values and if you want to paste it with all format then do this

```
Sub pop1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        r = 19

        For i = 1 To 21
            .Range("S16:Y16").Copy
            .Range("S" & r).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            r = r + 3
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a razon to make the copy inside the cycle, 20 time, and not 1 time before the cycle? (Im learning too, and anyway +1)

Comment: @qPCR4vir: Yes there is a reason. Putting it inside the loop is a precaution. If any code runs say because of `Worksheet_Change` while pasting then it will clear the clipboard and you will get an error when you try to paste again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not cut out the loop **only if you don't have values below it you want to keep** otherwise other answer are already provided:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("S16:Y16").resize(3)'changed range to include 2 rows bellow 

r(1,1).Offset(R.count, 0).resize(R.count*20).value = R.value
```

*Please forgive any syntax errors as I'm on my mobile. I'm happy to fix if you find errors.*

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
Sub pop1()
    '  Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+f
    '
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("S16:Y16")
    r.Copy  

    For i = 1 To 20
        r.Offset(3 * i, 0).PasteSpecial
     Next i
End Sub
```

or this mininimalist:

```
Sub pop1()
    '  Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+f

  Range("S16:Y16").Copy

    For i = 1 To 20
        Range("S16:Y16").Offset(3 * i, 0).PasteSpecial
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code :

```
Sub pop1()
    '  Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+f
    '
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("S16:Y16")

    j = 16
    For i = 1 To 20
        j = j + 3
         rng.Copy Range("S" & j)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I was working on solution and when it was ready already there was an answer. I did noticed a very similar answer exist but as i dont wanted to waste my efforts i posted it.

Comment: Yes I want it to paste 20 times then stop.

Comment: @glh Sometimes solution can be similar. If you term it as copying not cool.

Comment: Thanks to everyone its working now. I am learning a lot thanks again